# Why the pictures flash in Chrome?

Tags: image, google-chrome, flash

I got a tricky question from our client. 
The pictures in Chrome flash when switching between each page, but in Firefox everything's fine.

I paste the website to describe clearly:
http://13.76.89.147/?service=%E4%BC%81%E6%A5%AD%E4%BD%B5%E8%B3%BC

As you see there is a list of categories in the left side, when we switch between each category, the logo on the top and the small picture in the right side flash for about one second every time. (in Chrome)

In the beginning I thought it's because of the bandwidth, but it flashes every time in Chrome but in Firefox it's normal!

Is there any solution? Thank you, we really need to find it!
Thanks for your great help!!

Terry

Comment: Adobe flash? Chrome not work more flash a check https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213033?hl=en

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean adobe flash. I mean the pictures will be flickering (for about one second) when switching between each page.  Actually I even don't think it's an issue, but our client think it needs to be solved....
Maybe you could check the website by using Chrome and Firefox to see the differences, if you only check it on Chrome you may also think there's nothing wrong.